# Find particular array elements with neighbours

Tags: python, optimization

I have the following numpy array:

```
data =   [[2 1 2 0 3 0 1 0 1]
          [4 0 1 2 3 3 4 4 1]
          [2 3 2 2 2 1 2 0 3]
          [0 3 1 3 4 0 0 3 2]]

data = np.array(data)
```

I want to write an efficient function (in terms of execution time) which returns indices of elements with a particular value, having neighbors of a another value. e.g. running the function `find_elements(data, 3, 2)` on above data should return the following:

```
result = [(4, 1), (1, 2)]
```

[image]

So far I've tried this:

```
def find_elements(data, value, neighbor_value):
    result = []
    ix = np.isin(data, [value])
    a_ix = np.where(ix)

    for y, x in itertools.izip(a_ix[0], a_ix[1]):
        if y == 0 or y == data.shape[0] - 1 or x == 0 or x == data.shape[1] - 1:
            continue

        if data[y - 1, x] == neighbor_value or data[y + 1, x] == neighbor_value or data[y, x - 1] == neighbor_value or data[y, x + 1] == neighbor_value:
            result.append((x, y))

    return result
```

**Question:** Is there any way I could specify the neighbor elements in numpy filtering? or is there already a builtin function in any library that provides this functionality?